# Align 3 divs for responsive design

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

How do I align these 3 divs like: pickup:left, phone:middle, delivery: right? I've seen the other align div's problems from stackoverflow but somehow they won't work for my code. I need those div's to keep their position for a media between (600px-900px), I mean if I have right now on the screen 600px and I resize it to 900px the div's should have the same position.

This is the html

```
        <div class="shrinkTopBar">
      <div class="phone">
        <img src="images/pick_it.png" alt="Phone number" />
        <h3>07917569024</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="pickup">
        <img src="images/pick_it.png" alt="Pick it up" />
        <div class="info">
          <h6>Pickup: Yes</h6>
          <p>Borehamwood,London</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="delivery">
        <img src="images/ship_it.png" alt="Deliver it" />
        <div class="info">
          <h6>Delivered: Yes</h6>
          <p>£5.00</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and this is my css

```
.topBar .shrinkTopBar {
width: 80%;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 30px;
text-align: center;
display: flex;
}

.topBar .phone {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
width: 175px;
height: 40px;
}

.topBar .pickup {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
width: 129px;
height: 40px;
}

.topBar .delivery {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
width: 129px;
height: 40px;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: what browsers do you need to support?

Comment: `should have the same position.` --> elaborate ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Should have the same position==> I mean they the phone div:center, pickup:left and delivery: right.

Comment: @IvanSanz-Carasa I need to support moz, chrome and safari

Comment: `justify-content:space-between` to the container

Comment: @TemaniAfif thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="shrinkTopBar">
 <div class="mrg">
  <div class="phone box-in">
    <img src="images/pick_it.png" alt="Phone number" />
    <h3>07917569024</h6>
  </div>
  <div class="pickup box-in">
    <img src="images/pick_it.png" alt="Pick it up" />
    <div class="info">
      <h6>Pickup: Yes</h6>
      <p>Borehamwood,London</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="delivery box-in">
    <img src="images/ship_it.png" alt="Deliver it" />
    <div class="info">
      <h6>Delivered: Yes</h6>
      <p>£5.00</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
.shrinkTopBar .mrg{

    margin:-20px -10px 0;
    }
    .shrinkTopBar .box-in{
    float:left:
    width:33.33%;
    padding:20px 15px 0;
    }
```

Comment: This answer gives no explanation as to what it does or how it works and doesn't fit the Stack Overflow purpose. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer In addition, the `<img>` tag does not use or need a closing slash and never has.